# I want "Text starts with" conditional formatting but only if a checkbox is checked. How can I achieve this?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Stack Exchange! Today I wish to use Google Sheets' conditional formatting option "text starts with" to blur out a range of cells (by changing color of text and background). That is the easy part which I know. The hard part which I'm asking about is the checkbox. How can I code the conditional formatting to apply IF checkbox = true AND text starts with "X"?

Here is a link to a demo sheet which simplifies the task at hand.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17f8vUkfT_kJR0F7NwWIAZK-RCchTg09yXj_dhfSbBz8/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Where is the text that you want to format conditionally? Please show your _manually entered_ desired results, for example in the scenario where A, B, C and E are checked and D is unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the file at [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYFtwUVlKbt9FGtrf3EDvStyJ2qbpje76N3MXBL9eRo/edit?usp=sharing) that use this formula for the custom formatting of range B7:F11

```
=and(B$2=true,OR(left(B7,1)="A",left(B7,1)="B",left(B7,1)="C",left(B7,1)="D",left(B7,1)="E"))
```

[image: cond]

Comment: I tried your formula which at first glance works. But when I unchecked the A column of data, the formula which creates the table shifted up and left. Thus resulting with your conditional formatting applying to the wrong column.

Comment: You did bring to my attention the "left" function. I'll see if I can code something which solves my problem.

Comment: In the real sheet (not the demo sheet), I applied the 'left' function you brought my attention to and was able to write ```=if((and($B$13=false, if(left(C19,1)="ʔ",true,false))),true)```.